# WITH ROLLUP not working properly

Tags: mysql, database, rollup

Here I'm showing the year of the order in the first column, the month in the second, Order_id in the third. I want to display totals by month and by year and grand totals.

This is the result I'm trying to get:

[image]

Month total, Year total and Grand total.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT coalesce(extract(year FROM order_date), 'Grand Total') as 'Year'
    , CASE  when extract(year FROM order_date) is null then ' '
        when extract(month FROM order_date) is null then 'Year total'
        else extract(month FROM order_date)
    END as `Month`
    , CASE when extract(month FROM order_date) is null Then ' '
        else coalesce(oh.order_id, 'Month Total')
    END as 'Order ID'
    , sum(quantity * order_price) AS 'AmntDue'
    , sum(quantity) AS 'NumBooksPurch'
FROM a_bkorders.order_headers oh
JOIN a_bkorders.order_details od on oh.order_id = od.order_id
GROUP BY extract(year FROM order_date), extract(month FROM order_date), oh.order_id with rollup
;
```

But this what I get:

[image]

The month total seems to work fine but not the yearly total or the grand total. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you post a sample of the data for us to reproduce the results with a fiddle?

Comment: Sure, I have attached the .sql file for the datebase a_bkorders.order_headers at this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8bvMX0U7f71SFFUR0RaTkVhOTA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So I know what the problem is, but I'm not completely sure what the solution is. I'm working on it right now... basically the with rollup is only getting applied to your order_id column.. so you are getting the results you want for those.. just by messing around I got 1 grand total and 3 year total results and then the month totals, but its not correct yet, so i'll see what  I can do.. but I'm not a mysql expert so I may refer someone else to this question if I can't figure it out :)

Comment: +1 for the well formatted question with appropriate data and attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't guarentee this will work because I don't have all of the data (aka the order amounts from the second table).. but I think something like this will work. let me know if its goofing up.

```
SELECT
    Year, 
    IF(Year = 'Grand Total', ' ', Month), 
    IF(Month = 'Year Total' OR Year = 'Grand Total', ' ', Ordered_ID),
    AmntDue, 
    NumberOfBooksPurch 
FROM(
    SELECT
        COALESCE(Year, 'Grand Total') AS Year,
        CASE 
            WHEN Year IS NULL THEN ' ' 
            ELSE COALESCE(MONTH, 'Year Total') 
        END AS Month,
        Ordered_ID,
        AmntDue, 
        NumberOfBooksPurch
    FROM (
        SELECT   
            YEAR(order_date) AS Year, 
            MONTH(order_date) AS Month,
            CASE 
                WHEN MONTH(order_date) IS NULL THEN ' '
                ELSE COALESCE(order_id, 'Month Total')
            END as Ordered_ID,
            SUM(quantity * order_price) AS AmntDue,
            COUNT(order_id) AS NumberOfBooksPurch
        FROM a_bkorders.order_headers
        JOIN a_bkorders.order_details USING (order_id)
        GROUP BY Year, Month, order_id WITH ROLLUP
    ) temp_table_alias
) final_temp_table;
```

Comment: This wont actually produce everything you want... gimme a sec.. i'll update so it puts in empty value for the correct rows as well

Comment: What you did works perfectly fine, Thank you! So is that mean that I had to use a subquery when I have multiple tables involved with a rollup? How come my way didn't work?

Comment: the with rollup is a pretty tricky operator... when you have multiple rows you want to rollup on a subquery so it will get applied to all of them. i just updated with the correct query that should return the expected results you asked for

Comment: I figured it out, I put the :                                                                 , CASE when Month is null Then ' '
else coalesce(Ordered_ID, 'Month Total')
END as 'Order ID        in the main query.

Comment: I also removed `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM order_date)` because you can do the same thing with `MONTH(order_date)`... its just easier to read and use :)

Comment: Man.... Excellent. Thank you for the help, I've been messing with it the whole day.